# TinyMCE not changin list items to BBCODE

Tags: tinymce, bbcode

I have set the TinyMCE to write everything in BBcode which works on everything except list items. TinyMCE puts out:

```
<ul>
   <li> text </li>
</ul>
```

But is should be:

```
[list]
[*]text
[/list]
```

I use TinyMCE version 4.0b3.

My TinyMCE code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "modern",
        mode : "exact",
        elements : "use",
        plugins : "link image searchreplace fullscreen textcolor insertdatetime charmap hr nonbreaking anchor table preview  bbcode", 

        toolbar1 : "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | outdent indent", 
        toolbar2 : "image table | forecolor backcolor | fontsizeselect" ,
        toolbar3 : "searchreplace | fullscreen | charmap",

        content_css : "style.css",

        entity_encoding : "raw",
        relative_urls : false,
        remove_script_host : false,
        convert_urls : true,
        nonbreaking_force_tab: true,
    });
```